# Node Application Heroku Application Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I am using `heroku/nodejs` build pack.

this is how my scripts in package.json look like:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
  "server": "http-server public -p 3000 -a localhost -c 0",
  "prod": "npm run build && npm run server",
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
  "lint": "eslint . --fix"
},
```

In procfile I have only one line of code:

`web: npm run prod`

Any ideas why am I seeing application error?

Comment: I think we'll need some more info. Try running "heroku logs --tail " from the heroku cli. This site I found may help: https://kb.heroku.com/why-am-i-seeing-application-error

Comment: You need to use the $PORT env from Heroku in your "server" script, instead of the 3000 port.

Comment: If you post that "server" command should be simple `http-server` I will accept your answer. It took me some googling and debugging though. Also heroku apparentely does not install dev dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the error, I think that you should be using the environment variable `$PORT` i.e. `http-server public -p $PORT -c 0` Make sure you have `http-server` in you deps and not your devDeps.

This might not be causing the error but you shouldn't do your build on run. Instead add the build step to a `postinstall` NPM script like below.

`"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
  "postinstall": "npm run build",
  "server": "http-server public -p $PORT -c 0",
  "prod": "npm run server",
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
  "lint": "eslint . --fix"
},`

This will ensure that your build gets run on deployment and not every time the node process starts.

Comment: FYI you don't need a `procfile` if you have a `npm run start` I would simply rename `prod` to `start` and delete `procfile`